# Change the input type of the sha1 alg

Tags: java, algorithm, sha1

I am faced with a curious task. I have to generate a SHA1 hash based on an input parameter. Input is the following input `303934393837353974570C61944628F63032313430303030303043384137` and the result of the sha1 hash should be `89b302d863e996d73f6fcbcf20489969ca4d593c`.

But if I try following:

```
   var result = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex( input);
```

The result will be `e099219046775bc9528599c3077f7f49756f9bb1`.

The curious is, thus the online converter [SHA-Online-Tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha1.html) if I change the input type, then the result will be as expected.

For any hint I am grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the output you get from the online tool by selecting the input type as hex. It means the input string is a hex of the original string. So you need to decode hex to a string first and calculate sha1.

```
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex("303934393837353974570C61944628F63032313430303030303043384137"))
```

Will give you output `89b302d863e996d73f6fcbcf20489969ca4d593c`